# get a binary tree of height n + 1 from one of height n

Tags: binary-tree

"To get a binary tree of height n + 1 from one of height n, we can create, at most, two leaves in place of each previous one."
Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata - Peter Linz

Could someone explain to me (visually) how we get here a binary tree of height n + 1 by just doubling the leaves?

Comment: What is the source of your quote? Can you add a a link inside your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words to stress in the quote are **"in place of"**.

Here is an example of a binary tree with height 2:

```
           1
          / \
         2   3
        /
       4
```

It has two leaves: one with value 3 and one with value 4.

If we replace each of those leaves with a little subtree that has a parent node with 2 leaves, then we get:

```
           1
          / \
         2   3
        /   / \ 
       4   c   d
      / \
     a   b
```

Here we see that the resulting tree has height 3.

In general, when a tree has a height of , then there is **at least** one leaf at level  in that tree (when starting the level numbering at 0). When that leaf is replaced with a little subtree with a parent node that has 2 leaves, it is clear that those new leaves reside on level  + 1, giving the tree a height of  + 1.

The words *"at most, two leaves"* indicate that the above would also work if we replaced the existing leaves with little subtrees that just have a parent with **one** leaf.